# how to make a container with holes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a tutorial on how to use my app for the first time.

So it looks like a popup about how to use a button

during the tutorial, I want to make the background darker and a circle appears that will circle the button and there is a tutorial text

So, I want to make a container that has circular holes

here's a simple example:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .dark{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.377);
    }
    .circle{
      height: 150px;
      width: 150px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dark">
    <p style="color:white;font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;font-size: 23px;">This button is used to delete your file.</p>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <button style="margin:200px;">The Button</button>
</body>
```

but I want the hole to be in the button

Comment: You can apply some margin to the circle, or use positioning

Comment: not working. the hole's color is'nt transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Updated the code example to contain the overlay by adding a `<main>` container with `overflow: hidden`, so the snippet displays more properly.

**Original**

Just posting as an alternative solution:

After some experiments, I came up with this new method that actually display a transparent circle instead of one with a white background, hopefully it's closer to the desired behavior of a hole.

This allows other elements beside the button to be seen through, and it also keeps the button interactive so it can accept hover and click effects properly.

Run this snippet to see the result:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      main {
       display: flex;
       width: 100%;
       min-height: 100vh;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: flex-start;
       overflow: hidden;
      }

      section {
        min-height: 300px;
        min-width: 500px;
        background: pink;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 16px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background: pink;
      }

      div {
        display: flex;
        background: pink;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 8px;
      }

      button {
        padding: 5px;
      }

      .highlight {
        position: relative;
        isolation: isolate;
      }

      .btn-wrap.highlight::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 10000px;
        height: 10000px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: radial-gradient(
          circle,
          rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1%,
          rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.377) 1.01%
        );
        z-index: -1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h3>This button is used to delete your file</h3>
      <div class="btn-wrap highlight">
        <button>The Button</button>
      </div>
    </section>
    </main>
  </body>
```

Comment: hmm.. can u give the full code??

Comment: Just noticed only the button text is on top of backdrop now, I'll wrap the button in a div to fix it in 2 min

Comment: @Rob I actually came up with a new solution to make a real transparent circle, it took me a while to think it through but it does give interesting results, might as well check it out for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .dark{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.377);
    }
    .circle{
      height: 150px;
      width: 150px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: white;
    }
    button {
      position:relative; /* ::before position absolute relative to this. */
      isolation: isolate; /* contain z-index; */
      overflow: visible; /* cater for circle pseudo element */
      color: white;
      background-color: purple; /* this not seen because ::after used for background colour */
    }
    button::before {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -2;
      inset: -4.5em -2.5em;
      /*  .circle code */
      width: 200%;
      aspect-ratio: 1;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: white;
    }
     button::after {
     content: " ";
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1;
     inset: 0;
     background-color: purple;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dark">
    <p style="color:white;font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;font-size: 23px;">This button is used to delete your file.</p>
    <!--  <div class="circle"></div> -->
  </div>
  <button style="margin:200px;">The Button</button>
</body>
```